# Average that changes at the end of each month - dynamic formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I'm trying to build a cash flow spreadsheet and finding it difficult to find the right formula.

I would like to calculate the last 6 months average starting from this month - 1, average of june to october and the formula adapts each end of month

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWzcB.png)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The formula is very straightforward.

Cell H3 formula:

```
    =AVERAGE(B2:G2)
```

So for July, we're calculating the average of January through June. Drag the formula to the right.

[image]

You didn't mention that you need the average to be populated anywhere special, which is why I posed the answer as such. If you want to display the most recent average elsewhere, then you could input this formula into the desired cell:

```
    =LOOKUP(2,1/(A3:M3<>""),A3:M3)
```

This will pull the last non-empty cell between cells A3 through M3.

Comment: Hello Isolated, thank you for your reponse. is it possible to calculate this average in N2 and it changes as we add new colons / month

Comment: @Mugen One way is to put that last formula in cell N2. But perhaps you don't want row 3, so another approach is needed. I'll ponder a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have A1 to F1 the numbers to average. G1 is =AVERAGE(A1:F1). The problem comes when you add a column for the new data between F1 and G1. The formula now moves to H1 but the references stay the same (weirdly enough if you now type a number in G1, the formula in H1 will auto-update to include it A1:G1 - at least on newer versions of Excel). To make it dynamic (i.e. always average the first six cells to the left) use the offset formula in G1:

=AVERAGE(OFFSET(G1,0,-6,1,6))

A small caveat here. OFFSET is a volatile function, which means Excel will recalculate it on any change in the workbook (or any other open workbook for that matter) because it cannot determine a static dependency tree for that cell to only change/recalculate when its dependancies change. Now this is not a problem for small spreadsheets but with large datasets things can get real slow real quick. The better solution uses the INDEX function to effectively pick out the correct six numbers in the whole row based on its absolute  position in said the row. G1 becomes

=AVERAGE(INDEX(A1:G1, COLUMN()-COLUMN(A1)-5):INDEX(A1:G1, COLUMN()-COLUMN(A1)))

Its important to make the indexed array reference till G1 (ie. include itself). This might seem like a circular reference but it will ensure that the array keeps growing as you insert more columns.

Keeping the best for last, enter "dynamic named ranges"! I love this elegant solution albeit semi-obscure (read excel magic). Make sure G1 is selected. Click Formulas > Define Name. Give your range the name "sixleft", change scope to Sheet1 (or whatever your sheet is called) and set "refers to" to =Sheet1!A1:F1 and click ok. Now enter into G1:

=AVERAGE(sixleft)